# Automatically mount external hard drive into Samba share

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount, network-shares, samba

I have setup my Raspberry Pi home server, one short-coming is if I unplug 1 of my external hard drives, use it, and plug it back in to the Pi, this drive is not recognized/readable, it returns an input/output error

now my fstab automounts my hard drives into my home partition using their UUID to insert into the correct folder, but this only happens on boot, and not during "runtime"

how should I go about auto mounting a hard drive / usb storage device while Pi & samba is running?

Comment: And you found the error message where, and it said what? And what kind of drive is it, does it have a separate supply, or does it get its power via USB? And it's not one of two RAID1 drives, right?

Comment: @ClassStacker error message found in the terminal, msg="it returns an input/output error", drive type, powersupply (wall/usb) - does that really make a difference? Raid no. Just 2 simple GPT 2Tb and 3Tb drives

Comment: Take a look at autofs. I think that might be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

So how the i got this fixed last time was:

Add:
`rootdelay=10` to the end of cmdline.txt

Refer https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/824 for more information.

Comment: I do not, if this solves it, I will kick myself

Comment: The `auto` option controls only the behavior of `mount -a`, which is typically executed on boot. It is not related to automounting while the system is running.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling you are correct, this does not work

Comment: Yes you are right my mistake. I found out what i did last time to fix my problem. So the answer will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use autofs, ref.:

[Remount a windows/samba share under Linux when windows server (re)starts](https://superuser.com/questions/1137406/remount-a-windows-samba-share-under-linux-when-windows-server-restarts/1141108#1141108)

The solution is for auto (re)mounting a windows share but the method may be used for all types of shares