# Remount a windows/samba share under Linux when windows server (re)starts

Tags: linux, mount

The windows share has been mounted by fstab and works but the share is lost when the share-host is rebooted

Is there a way to configure the share to be automounted when the share-host returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use autofs to achive this

```
#Create sharepoint at: /sharebase/share
service autofs stop
nano /etc/auto.master
    Add: /sharebase /etc/auto.cifs --timeout=300 --ghost
nano /etc/auto.cifs
    Add: share   -fstype=cifs,domain=mydomain,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/root/.cifs ://SAMBA.share/
nano /root/.cifs
    Add: username=myusername
    Add: password=mypassword
service autofs start
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit as Root **/etc/fstab**

```
add //Ip_Server/folder_server /folder_local cifs username=user_windows,password=password-windows,rw,users,uid=user_linux,gid=group_linux 0 0
```

Example:

```
//192.168.0.100/FolderInWin\share_Folder_InWin /home/pepe/MyFolder cifs username=pepeinWin,password=pepeinWin1234,rw,users,uid=pepe,gid=users 0 0
```

It will mount each time you boot your PC

Comment: The share is located on a windows server and declared in /etc/fstab on a linux-server:
//192.168.0.100/felles/ /home/user/custom/share/ cifs ro,domain=our.domain,uid=www-data,gid=www-data,credentials=/etc/smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
The problem is that the linux-server are loosing the share if the windows machine restarts